# Apps Not getting downloaded from Appmanager and EMM store on my Ipad

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-iot

I am trying to download the apps from the App-manager and EMM store from my       Ipad, but the app is not getting downloaded, it is showing a message:

> Could not connect to <My IP>.

Comment: What is the EMM version that you are using? Can you attach the stacktrace to get a better understanding.

Comment: EMM 2.1.0(Alpha), also tired in EMM(2.0.1) and Appmanager (1.1.0)

Comment: Do you get any errors in the backend? Can you edit the question attaching the stacktrace to get a better idea